# What is this Sonix Technology Driver update about?

Tags: windows-11

[image]

The link forwards to the generic windows help page. No real info available.

Comment: So what Sonix device do you have?

Comment: I dont know, a Lenovo message popped up and here I am.

Comment: Have you looked in the device manager?

Comment: I did now and tried to find anything looking like something "Sonix". Unsuccessfully though

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

#### What is this Sonix Technology Driver update about?

Lenovo provides drivers for Sonix cameras.

Example:

> This package provides Camera Driver (Realtek, Sonix) and is supported on Legion 7-16ACHg6 and running the following Operating Systems: Windows 11 (64-bit)

Source: [Camera Driver (Realtek, Sonix) for Windows 11 (64-bit) - Legion 7-16ACHg6 - Lenovo Support SV](https://support.lenovo.com/sv/en/downloads/ds551550-camera-driver-realtek-sonix-for-windows-11-64-bit-legion-7-16achg6)

The above link includes "Find your Product". Enter your Lenovo serial number and it should locate the correct drivers for your Lenovo device. You can also click the "Detect Product" button.